# Add script tags on child templates in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, templates

I have a child template in my MVC project where I want to initialize a Javascript framework. This should not be done on the master template, as I need some razor code on the page to work with the framework. The framework in question is [Bootstrap-Year-Calendar](http://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/#Documentation/Installation), which I need to have talk to an SQL Database. Each child template will receive different data, so I cannot put the code on the master template for this. But if a place a script tag on the child template with the code to initialize the framework:

```
$('#calendar').calendar({
        displayWeekNumber: true,
        customDayRenderer: function (element, date) {
            $(element).css('background-color', 'red');
            $(element).css('color', 'white');
            $(element).css('border-radius', '15px');
        }
    });
```

But when I put the script tag with the code on my child template I receive this error:

> TypeError: $(...).calendar is not a function

I have the .js and .css files included n my master template, so they should be available to use on the child template. My project was made with Umraco CMS as well.

How can I display the calendar on my child templates?

Comment: I solved it by simply putting the script tag for the framework in the head.

Comment: It is unable to find your `calendar` library. Make sure it is added properly to the child template via a script tag